# Retrieve values corresponding to numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have a list of numbers, where each one has two corresponding numbers like this:

```
1: 30 and 60
2: 70 and 100
3: 120 and 150
```

I would like to get both numbers corresponding to a given number. For example, if I look up 2, I would retrieve 70 and 100.

What is the best data type to store and retrieve this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary with tuples

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>>();
dic.Add(1, Tuple.Create(30, 60));
dic.Add(2, Tuple.Create(70, 100));
dic.Add(3, Tuple.Create(120, 150));
```

Then if for example you want to get both numbers corresponding to for example 3

```
dic.TryGetValue(3, out Tuple<int, int> res);
var firstNumber= res.Item1; //this should be 120
var secondNumber = res.Item2; //this should be 150
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ended up using your solution, because seemed easier

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

This is good example of [Encapsulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming) pillar of OOP:

> Encapsulation means that a group of related properties, methods, and
>   other members are treated as a single unit or object.

You can create a class with three properties Id, Number1 and Number2 respectively. In this way it will be easier for you to keep relationship between  all three numbers

```
public class Numbers
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Number1 { get; set; }
   public int Number2 { get; set; }

   public Numbers(int id, int num1, int num2)
   { 
       this.Id = id;
       this.Number1 = num1;
       this.Number2 = num2;
   }
}
```

You have list of Numbers like,

```
 List<Numbers> NumberList = new List<Numbers>()
 { 
      new Numbers(1, 30, 60),
      new Numbers(2, 70, 100),
      new Numbers(3, 120, 150)
 }
```

Now if you want to filter it by pair by Id, then

```
 using System.Linq; 
 ...
 var result = NumberList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3);
 Console.WriteLine($"{result.Id}: {result.Number1} and {result.Number2}");
```

---

Output:

```
3: 120 and 150.
```

---

What is the best data type to store / retrieve this information?

To store numeric data, C# provide `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double` datatypes. You can choose any of the data type as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: I am glad that my answer helped you